# Image inside div full width of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to have image  inside div element which has width of 500px. But I need that this image is set to full width of screen. That means:

```
<div style='width:500px'>Some text <img full width of screen /> some other text </div>
```

But I need that image size is for full width of screen. That means that I don't need to have image only for 500px I need that this image is resizable of screen width. This img must be inside this div element. Thank you

Comment: You're not very clear, but setting the style `position: fixed; width: 100%` would do that, but it would also do certain other things, such as take the image out of the document flow.

Comment: You are not too clear about your issue. You want an image inside div(of 500px width), you also want it to be the size of screen, so what if screen is greater than 500px. Its totally complicated to understand.

Comment: Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/K4UR4/269/ There you can see the I don't see correctly the text at the top of page...hmm

Answer (score 2):

Just set the position of your image to fixed, 
the width and the height to 100% 
and the top and left to 0.

It will then be fullscreen in your browser.

```
img{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

In your example:

```
<div style='width:500px'>Some text 
  <img style="background: red; width: 100%;height: 100%; position: fixed;
  left: 0;top:0" full width of screen /> 
some other text 
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you this is almost OK but there is problem height can not be 100% but only 100px...Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/K4UR4/269/

Comment: You've set your height to 100px in html, change this to 100%

Comment: Hello. It can not be 100% it must be set to 100px...The first text must be on the top of page and the text after img must be after img like standard img in div....Thank you